# How would I randomly generate a 3d world in Godot?

Tags: random, godot, procedural-generation, gdscript

I am trying to create a grid-based randomly generated world. The way it will work is by randomly choosing from an array of possible world chunks, and then spawning 9 of them in a 3x3 grid. However, to do this, I need to know how to add nodes to an array, as well as move around a child node, either before or after adding it to the scene tree. I know the theory behind all of this, I just need the commands used by Godot to achieve this. What are they? Also, if you need any additional information to answer, please tell me.

Comment: Did you try programming? Post the code you already have or try to script something than come and ask if you'll still have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

> However, to do this, I need to know how to add nodes to an array

Look at this code:

```
var _objToSpawn : PackedScene = preload('res://path_to_object.tscn')
var _nodeArr : Array = []

func _spawnObjectAndAddToArr() -> void:
    var newObj : ObjectClass = _objToSpawn.instance()
    add_child(newObj)
    
    _nodeArr.append(newObj)
```

That code loads a scene from a file, creates a new array, then defines a function which spawns the loaded file, adds it as a child of the current node, and adds it to an array which is defined beforehand.

> as well as move around a child node, either before or after adding it to the scene tree

In 3d, for an object to have a position, it must ultimately extend Spatial. Then you change the object's `translation` or `transform.origin`

```
var _objToSpawn : PackedScene = preload('res://path_to_object.tscn')
var _nodeArr : Array = []

func _spawnObjectAndAddToArr() -> void:
    var newObj : ObjectClass = _objToSpawn.instance()
    add_child(newObj)

    newObj.translation = translation
    
    _nodeArr.append(newObj)
```

EDIT: Also, if you want to add it to the scene tree, then instead of `add_child`, use `get_tree().current_scene.add_child`

Comment: Thanks for that @Dylan_Turner.  I'm trying to do something similar, will have look at this after I've done the tutorial. I posted a question on SO about documentation for GoDot Nodes that you may be able to answer.